# Different colour markers or ID numbers for different coordinates with legend in leaflet

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet, markers

I have a data set on 44 health facility locations (Longitude and Latitude), facility name, type and ID.

The task I need to execute are:
1a) I want to map the facility locations each having different colour markers and then
1b) assign the facility names according to the colour codes as legends

Also, I wish to accomplish the following:

2a) I want to map the facility locations with their respective ID numbers (from 1 to 44) on the map and then
2b) assign the facility names according to their ID numbers as legends.

I have started developing the map using leaflet package in R. Below are my initial codes which only put the facility names on the locations using the default pop-up:

```
library(leaflet)
```

leaflet(data = d1) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude,label = ~as.character(Facility.Name))

[map of facility locations for the above codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yfnx.png)

Here, d1 is my dataframe containing my variables (id, facility name and type, Longitude, Latitude).
Below is reproducible example:

[Data set for reproducible example: username is jmk and the password is jascalla25. Open the document for the data set](https://drive.flipdrive.com/drive/lrOb7BMfkb4MYLHxPixxqhkhljbMW74V)

How can I achieve my task stated in items 1a to 2b above?

Comment: Cartographically speaking I suggest using the same colour for the markers and labeling them or using a popup to differentiate them. This is because we can only really tell <10 colours apart so having 44 is crazy. Also a legend with 44 entries will take up too much space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. The first one I did was to use same colour marker and label them on the map. I will take the suggestion that using the same colour for the markers and to use different popup to differentiate them. How can I differentiate the popup in my earlier code?  My code is: leaflet(data = d1) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude,label = ~as.character(Facility.Name))

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in R sorry. In JavaScript I use bindpopup